# Mysql profiling items and selecting matching profiles

Tags: mysql, select, profiling, match

Is there efficient algorithm to determine items profiles and select the matching ones with a query?

for example

```
TABLE MEN
id name
1  man1
2  man2
3  man3


TABLE PROPERTIES
id  name
1   health_points
2   strenght
3   speed


TABLE MEN_PROPERTIES
id  man_id  property_id  property_counter
1   1       1            1000
2   1       2            100
3   1       3            50
4   2       1            100
5   2       2            200
6   2       3            100
7   3       1            100
8   3       2            10
9   3       3            5
```

This means

```
man1 {
    health_point:1000,
    strenght:100
    speed:50
}

man2 {
    health_point:100,
    strenght:200
    speed:100
}

man3 {
    health_point:100,
    strenght:10
    speed:5
}
```

let's say i am working on man_1, we visually understand its profile matches with man_3 profiles. I want mysql to return man_3 as a profile matching with man_1 profile.

What's the best way to achive the result?

Comment: why does man_3 matches with man_1?

Comment: well, it's balanced as man_1 but has lower values, i am looking for proportion matching

Comment: yes, if man3{health_point:100, strenght:20, speed:5} and man4 {health_point:100, strenght:10, speed:5} they both match but man_4 is the nearest

Comment: do you have any properties other than that?

Comment: yes, an undeterminated list...it can grow in time

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  x.*
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  a.ID, 
                    a.Name,
                    MAX(IF(c.Name = 'health_points', b.property_counter, NULL)) health_points,
                    MAX(IF(c.Name = 'strenght', b.property_counter, NULL)) strenght,
                    MAX(IF(c.Name = 'speed', b.property_counter, NULL)) speed
            FROM    Men a
                    INNER JOIN Men_Properties b
                        ON a.ID = b.man_ID
                    INNER JOIN Properties c
                        ON b.Property_ID = c.ID
            WHERE   a.ID <> 1
            GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
        ) x
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.ID, 
                    a.Name,
                    MAX(IF(c.Name = 'health_points', b.property_counter, NULL)) health_points,
                    MAX(IF(c.Name = 'strenght', b.property_counter, NULL)) strenght,
                    MAX(IF(c.Name = 'speed', b.property_counter, NULL)) speed
            FROM    Men a
                    INNER JOIN Men_Properties b
                        ON a.ID = b.man_ID
                    INNER JOIN Properties c
                        ON b.Property_ID = c.ID
            WHERE   a.ID  = 1
            GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
        ) y
WHERE   (x.health_points * 1.0 / y.health_points) = (x.strenght * 1.0 / y.strenght) AND
        (x.strenght * 1.0 / y.strenght) = (x.speed * 1.0 / y.speed)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e094e/5)

Comment: Ok now i need to understand it in depth! i'll be bac as soon as possibile :)

Comment: what the query does is it statically pivot the tables in a subquery and filter for a specific ID. The result of the subquery is then cross reference on all records.